# Could not find an overload for != - Swift iBeacon

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I am following a tutorial which can be found here http://ibeaconmodules.us/blogs/news/14702963-tutorial-swift-based-ibeacon-app-development-with-corelocation-on-apple-ios-7-8

The last part of the tutorial suggests I add the following code to the view controller

```
if(beacons != nil) {
    return beacons!.count
} else {
    return 0
}
```

In doing so I get the error posted in the message title. It appears that (from my limited knowledge and research) that it is because the beacons variable is not declared as optional? This could be my interpretation of reading similar stack overflow posts incorrectly.

Please could someone explain how i would go about fixing this? My two classes (app delegate and view controller are as follows)

```
extension AppDelegate: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    func sendLocalNotificationWithMessage(message: String!) {
        let notification:UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
        notification.alertBody = message
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
        didRangeBeacons beacons: [AnyObject],
        inRegion region: CLBeaconRegion!) {
            NSLog("didRangeBeacons");



            let viewController:ViewController = window!.rootViewController as! ViewController
            viewController.beacons = beacons as! [CLBeacon]
            viewController.tableView!.reloadData()


            var message:String = ""

            if(beacons.count > 0) {
                let nearestBeacon:CLBeacon = beacons[0] as! CLBeacon

                if(nearestBeacon.proximity == lastProximity ||
                    nearestBeacon.proximity == CLProximity.Unknown) {
                        return;
                }
                lastProximity = nearestBeacon.proximity;

                switch nearestBeacon.proximity {
                case CLProximity.Far:
                    message = "You are far away from the beacon"
                case CLProximity.Near:
                    message = "You are near the beacon"
                case CLProximity.Immediate:
                    message = "You are in the immediate proximity of the beacon"
                case CLProximity.Unknown:
                    return
                }
            } else {
                message = "No beacons are nearby"
            }

            NSLog("%@", message)
            sendLocalNotificationWithMessage(message)
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
        didEnterRegion region: CLRegion!) {
            manager.startRangingBeaconsInRegion(region as! CLBeaconRegion)
            manager.startUpdatingLocation()

            NSLog("You entered the region")
            sendLocalNotificationWithMessage("You entered the region")
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!,
        didExitRegion region: CLRegion!) {
            manager.stopRangingBeaconsInRegion(region as! CLBeaconRegion)
            manager.stopUpdatingLocation()

            NSLog("You exited the region")
            sendLocalNotificationWithMessage("You exited the region")
    }
}
```

view controller

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView?
    var beacons: [CLBeacon] = []


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

            if(beacons != nil) {
                return beacons!.count
            } else {
                return 0
            }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView,
        cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            var cell:UITableViewCell? =
            tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyIdentifier") as? UITableViewCell

            if(cell == nil) {
                cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle,
                    reuseIdentifier: "MyIdentifier")
                cell!.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
            }

            let beacon:CLBeacon = beacons[indexPath.row]
            var proximityLabel:String! = ""

            switch beacon.proximity {
            case CLProximity.Far:
                proximityLabel = "Far"
            case CLProximity.Near:
                proximityLabel = "Near"
            case CLProximity.Immediate:
                proximityLabel = "Immediate"
            case CLProximity.Unknown:
                proximityLabel = "Unknown"
            }

            cell!.textLabel!.text = proximityLabel

            let detailLabel:String = "Major: \(beacon.major.integerValue), " +
                "Minor: \(beacon.minor.integerValue), " +
                "RSSI: \(beacon.rssi as Int), " +
            "UUID: \(beacon.proximityUUID.UUIDString)"
            cell!.detailTextLabel!.text = detailLabel

            return cell!
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

}
```

Comment: It appears that in your code `beacons ` is not an optional value. You can remove this entire check and just more forward.

Comment: please post that as an answer and i will accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that in your code `beacons` is not an optional value. You can remove this entire check and just more forward.